# Getting weka to cross-validate a classifier from Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, weka, rjb

Taking a hint from [here](http://www.tylerclemons.com/weka-and-ruby/)! I'm utilising weka's library of classifiers from Ruby via RJB.

I want to be able to create a classifier from an .arff file and run 10 fold cross-validation with it to produce a confusion matrix as explained [in the Weka wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+classifier+evaluation+output+manually).

Below is the essential code involved.

```
# creating the classifier
Rjb::load("./weka.jar", jvmargs=["-Xmx2000M"])
classifier = Rjb::import("weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes").new

# importing the data
data_src = Rjb::import("java.io.FileReader").new("./the_data.arff")
data = Rjb::import("weka.core.Instances").new(data_src)

evaluation = Rjb::import("weka.classifiers.Evaluation").new(data)

folds = Rjb::import('java.lang.Integer').new(10)
rand = Rjb::import("java.util.Random").new(1)

evaluation.crossValidateModel(classifier, 
                              data, 
                              folds, 
                              rand )

print evaluation.toMatrixString()
```

From what I can tell from the weka wiki link above: this should work.
But...

```
Fail: unknown method name `crossValidateModel' (RuntimeError)
```

Which from what I understand usually means that the method in question hasn't been supplied with the correct arguments, but I can't see how this would be the case.

The output of **evaluation.java_methods** includes `crossValidateModel([Ljava.lang.String;Lweka.core.Instances;I[Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.util.Random;, Lweka.classifiers.Classifier;Lweka.core.Instances;ILjava.util.Random;[Ljava.lang.Object;])`

which I'm not sure how to interpret.

Does anyone out there know what I need to do?

---

EDIT: although I wasn't able to solve the problem as posed here, it turns out that I was able to achieve what I wanted by starting over with JRuby as described [here](http://rubyforscientificresearch.blogspot.com/search/label/WEKA). Thanks to michaeltwofish for the tip :)

Comment: can you print class of "classifier". Like print classifier.getClass(). It seems that overload for java does not work as you expected.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
`p classifier.getClass() # => 
#<Rjb::Weka_classifiers_bayes_NaiveBayes:0x00000101022360>`
does that help?

Comment: I don't know if there's a reason you have to use RJB, but for what it's worth, I've used Weka from JRuby to great effect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Rjb::import('java.lang.Integer').new(10) 
try to use plain 10.

You are calling a method crossValidateModel from Evaluation class. Which has a overload. see below. Notice that third parameter is int. You are using java.lang.Integer. In java int and Integer are not the same thing. Look for primitive types and Wrapper types in java if you are interested. Normally java is able to change between int and Integer since java 5. But you are calling from Rjb , I think java Integer is wrapped in some object for ruby purposes and that is confusing things.

From weka javadocs.

```
 crossValidateModel(Classifier, Instances, int)
```

Performs a (stratified if class is nominal) cross-validation for a classifier on a set of instances.

```
crossValidateModel(String, Instances, int, String[])
```

Performs a (stratified if class is nominal) cross-validation for a classifier on a set of instances.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help, or maybe there's something else wrong as well. Maybe I should just use JRuby like [here](http://rubyforscientificresearch.blogspot.com/2009/08/accessing-weka-from-jruby.html)